# Well formed formulas splittable over or condition

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose G is a set of well-formed formulas, and A and B are two well-formed formulas, I need to determine If G ⊢A or B then G ⊢A or G ⊢B This statement is true or false

My Thoughts: 
As per my understanding if G ⊢A then will mean G=A That is if G is true then A is 
true. And if G evaluates to false then A also evaluates to false 
So if I take G = {a or b} A = a or c and B = c or d then G ⊢A or B holds 
I am not sure how to approach this. Or produce a counter example

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the mathematical formulas in your MSE questions. As for the mathematics, try to find two formulas $A$ and $B$ that cover all possibilities for some eventuality together but not individually (you can forget about $G$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B= \lnot A$ and let $A$ be something that may or may not be true under $G$.  For example, $G$ might be the axioms for fields of characteristic $0$ and $A$ could be the statement: $\exists x~(x^2+1=0)$.  Then $G \vdash (A \lor \lnot A)$ but because $-1$ has a square root in some fields of characteristic $0$ but not in others, it's not true either that $G \vdash A$ or that $G \vdash \lnot A$.

Comment: That was awesome. But could you please give a simpler counter example?

Comment: Any statement that might be either true or false under $G$ will work.  $G$ could be the theory that states, "There are at least two distinct elements."  $A$ could then be the statement, "There are at least $94$ distinct elements."

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is purely within logic, ZFC math examples may greatly help you understand your confusion as with any other types of everyday examples. Notice your below statement is already false at the beginning of your manifested thought process.

> And if G evaluates to false then A also evaluates to false

Intuitively this doesn't make sense in general, as logic entailment is *not* the same as logical equivalence or biconditional.